# WSGI + Python + Flask возвращает неактуальные данные

Tags: python, apache, flask, wsgi

Создал тестовое приложение на Python фреймворке Flask. 
Приложение запускается через mod_wsgi веб-сервера Apache.
Приложение плохо реагирует на изменения исходного кода, показывая мне старые версии страниц. При этом каждый раз разные (2,3 изменения кода назад). Актуальную версию он показывает только после перезагрузки Апача. Режим дебага во Фласке включен. 
В чем еще может быть проблема?

Answer (score 3):

Лучше настроить uWSGI, тогда можно включить в `uwsgi.ini` опцию `python-autoreload = 1`. Мы именно так это используем, работает надёжно. От mod_wsgi и апача отказались в итоге в пользу nginx + uWSGI.

Кстати, режим дебага во фласке абсолютно бесполезен на боевом сервере, если сверху весь стек из "нгинкса" и uWSGI. С обработкой эксцепшнов, если есть syntax error, тоже беда. Поэтому для отладки - только dev server. Он для того и нужен, в общем-то. Или просто ещё не научились обработчик error 500 правильно делать.

Answer (score 1):

mod_wsgi имеет 2 режима работы: "embedded mode" и "daemon mode".
В первом случае, для применения изменений исходного кода требуется полная перезагрузка сервера. Для автоматического применения изменений, модуль должен быть запущен как "daemon mode". [Подробнее](https://modwsgi.readthedocs.io/en/develop/user-guides/reloading-source-code.html)